# Bootstrap Nav Container Fluid Center li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I center list items on a container-fluid navigation?  I have been jsfiddling with this for hours.  I havent gotten anything that works properly.  Looked over a ton of websites for answers.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-info navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    <a class="hidden-xs" href="#">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <div><img src="assets/img/logo-header-optimized.svg" alt="" height="52" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px"></div>
    </div>
    </a> <a class="visible-xs navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/phone-logo-header-optimized.svg" alt="" height="22"></a> </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="hidden-xs nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top:10px">
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse navbar-btn btn-raised" onclick="window.open('')"><strong> BOOK NOW </strong></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Introduction <i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Amenities <i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Hospitality <i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Information <i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: The div `<div class="navbar-header">` should have a "witdh:100%".

Second: between  insert a div with this `style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;"`

The `width: 60%` depending of elements

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution by Julian and it lowers the button on the left and I dont think he wants that. The two solutions that I have are to add one of 2 css styles.
First one `.navbar-header {padding: 0 300px;}` this will center the list items but will also move the image with it

Second one `.navbar-nav {padding: 0 300px;}` this will center the list items but will also bring the button closer to the middle but still in the same row as the image.

If you want to dig deeper, I recommend reading [this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support)